# multicolumn sorting of WinForms DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView in a windows form with 3 columns: Serial number, Name, and Date-Time.

The Name column will always have either of the two values: "name1" or "name2".

I need to sort these columns such that the grid displays all the rows with name values in a specific order (first display all the "name1" rows and then all the "name2" rows). Within the "name1" rows, I want the rows to be sorted by the Date-Time. Please note programmatically, all the 3 columns are strings.

For example, if I have the rows:

> 01 |Name1 | 2010-05-05 10:00 PM
>   02 |Name2 | 2010-05-02 08:00 AM
>   03 |Name2 | 2010-05-01 08:00 AM
>   04 |Name1 | 2010-05-01 11:00 AM
>   05 |Name1 | 2010-05-04 07:00 AM

needs to be sorted as

> 04 |Name1 | 2010-05-01 11:00 AM
>   05 |Name1 | 2010-05-04 07:00 AM
>   01 |Name1 | 2010-05-05 10:00 PM
>   03 |Name2 | 2010-05-01 08:00 AM
>   02 |Name2 | 2010-05-02 08:00 AM

I am not sure how to go about using the below:

```
myGrid.Sort(.....,ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: In almost a year you've asked over 30 questions and accepted <70%. You've answered 0 questions yourself and have asked 2x as many questions as the # of times you've even voted. One would think that you would at least want to upvote the answers people have left for you that you found helpful to your own queries. I personally have given an answer here, responded to your specific additional requests for clarifications 2x and done more research on each without feeling like you're trying to do a lot to help except for wait for me or the next person to give you the answer, so I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: @Bi: if the second column is string type, Name12 will sort before Name2.  i.e.  Name1, Name12, Name2. normalize your data.  and if possible, just sort it from database